# как продолжить цикл добавление пользователей в базу данных sqlite после исключения python

Tags: python, sqlite, циклы, исключения

пожалуйста помогите разобраться почему

код перестает работает если появляется ошибка UNIQUE constraint failed:

при добавления не уникального ид

мне нужно добавить в базу данных списки с данными пользователей, в которых возможно что ид пользователей уже существует. их нужно пропустить. и добавить только уникальных пользователей.
сейчас код перестает работать если пользователь не уникален.

```
import sqlite3


id = [12441, 21255021,]
name1 = ['name1', 'name2']
age1 = [ 23, 34]
city = ['city1', 'city2']
time = ['27.11.2022 4:15', '27.11.2022 4:15']



def insert_db(id, name1, age1, city, time):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('new_db.sqlite')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO test1 (id, name, age, city, joining_date,)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """, (id, name1, age1, city, time))
    connection.commit()


for i in range(len(id)):
    try:
        insert_db(id[i], name1[i], age1[i], city[i], time[i])
        print('уникальный')
    except:
        print('не уникальный')
```

Comment: Вы ведь сами и сказали, что ID должен быть уникальным. Просто перед записью данных в таблицу выполните проверку,  и если запись с таким ID уже есть, то просто пропустите данную итерацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import sqlite3

id = [12441, 21255021, ]
name1 = ['name1', 'name2']
age1 = [23, 34]
city = ['city1', 'city2']
time = ['27.11.2022 4:15', '27.11.2022 4:15']


def insert_db(id, name1, age1, city, time):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('new_db.sqlite')

    connection.execute(
        """
        create table if not exists test1
        (
            id           integer primary key,
            name         text,
            age          integer,
            city         text,
            joining_date text
        );
        """
    )

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO test1 (id, name, age, city, joining_date)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) on conflict do nothing returning id
    """, (id, name1, age1, city, time))

    inserted_id, = cursor.fetchone() or (None,)
    connection.commit()
    return inserted_id


for i in range(len(id)):
    if insert_db(id[i], name1[i], age1[i], city[i], time[i]):
        print('уникальный')
    else:
        print('не уникальный')
```

Нужно чтобы id был уникальным индексом, к примеру primary key